# Create XML sitemap in wordpress

Tags: xml

[This question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/15218/how-to-generate-update-a-xml-sitemap-without-plugins/36856#36856) has already been asked before, however, I cannot reply to those comments because I am a new user. Therefore, I will post my question here.

I am trying to create a XML sitemap for my wordpress site. Someone on this site suggested that a duplicate of the XML export file be made. This file is located [here](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.0.4/wp-admin/includes/export.php).

How can I modify this file in my theme so that it is updated automatically? Where will the exported file be located?

Comment: Have you considered using [a plugin](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=wordpress+xml+sitemap)?

Comment: Fir of all, thank you for your quick reply. I have actually. However, I have 2 custom post types on my website;books, lessons. I am hoping to garner a little more control over how google would index my site.

Comment: Please see the license in the footer (cc by-sa 3.0 with [attribution required](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/)), [edit] your question and link to the original question.

Comment: You seem to have skipped some research steps there. How does "export file" (?) has anything to do with sitemap?

Answer (score 1):

Latest versions of wordpress (since 5.2 IIRC) have the sitemap generation as part of the core functionallity. Plugins or code are not needed unless you need to customize its generation

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to achieve what you're looking to do with multiple sitemaps is with Yoast's Wordpress SEO plugin, which will generate a different sitemap for each of your custom post types, in addition to your blog posts and pages.

Answer (score -1):

Use a plugin like `Google sitemap plugin`, see: [google sitemap plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/google-sitemap-generator/)

Comment: Please see [answer]. Link only answers are discouraged and will be almost certainly downvoted. If you need to post more or less bare links, use a comment. You have rep enough for that.

Comment: It's the right answer tough? I will write it in a comment next time, but hope to get a vote then!

Comment: It is _an_ answer, and we care about answer quality here not just whether an answer technically fits. I would delete this and add it as a comment to question, or I can say with fair confidence that you will get votes just not the ones you want.

Comment: Don't forget the fun tough. Then next time I will provide some more context.