# Create html tree sitemap

Tags: php, html, sitemap

i am trying create html sitemap without plugin. How can i get all parents and his childs ? I want to create something like this

1. Main page

   - Category 1

     - post 1 of category 1
   - Category 2
2. Other page

   - Category 1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to generate/update a XML sitemap without plugins?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/15218/how-to-generate-update-a-xml-sitemap-without-plugins)

Comment: this is XML sitemap, without tree structure

Comment: Why would a category be a child of a page, they are not typically connected?